# Why doesn't `.getElementById` work on a node?

Tags: javascript, dom

I thing that if `.getElementById` were available on all nodes, there would be two main advantages:

1. **It could be possible to select nodes which don't belong to the document.**

   For example, I would like to do something like

   ```
   function foo(html){
       var el = document.createElement('div');
       el.innerHTML = html;
       var target = el.getElementById('target');
       /* Do something with `target` */
   }
   ```

   But I can't because I get `TypeError: el.getElementById is not a function`.

   Then, I don't want to use a class instead of an id, I must do

   ```
   function foo(html){
       var el = document.createElement('div');
       el.innerHTML = html;
       document.body.appendChild(el);
       var target = document.getElementById('target');
       document.body.removeChild(el);
       /* Do something with `target` */
   }
   ```

   But the document could already have an element with `id="target"`. Then, I should do

   ```
   function foo(html){
       var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
       iframe.onload = function(){
           var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document,
               el = document.createElement('div');
           el.innerHTML = html;
           doc.body.appendChild(el);
           var target = doc.getElementById('target');
           document.body.removeChild(iframe);
           /* Do something with `target` */
       };
       iframe.src = 'about:blank';
       document.body.appendChild(iframe);
   }
   ```

   But the code above doesn't work if I want `foo` to return something related with `html`, because the main code runs after, with the `onload` event.
2. **It could increase the performance, if the document has lots of elements and you know that the element you are searching is a descendant of an element that you already have in a variable**

   For example, if I have a document with the following structure:

   ```
   <body>
   <div id="div-1">
     <div id="div-1-1">
       <div id="div-1-1-1">
         ...
       </div>
       <div id="div-1-1-2">
         ...
       </div>
       ...
     </div>
     <div id="div-1-2">
       <div id="div-1-2-1">
     ...
       </div>
       <div id="div-1-2-2">
         ...
       </div>
         ...
     </div>
     ...
   </div>
   <div id="div-2">
     <div id="div-2-1">
       <div id="div-2-1-1">
         ...
       </div>
       <div id="div-2-1-2">
         ...
       </div>
        ...
     </div>
     <div id="div-2-2">
       <div id="div-2-2-1">
         ...
       </div>
       <div id="div-2-2-2">
         ...
       </div>
        ...
     </div>
     ...
   </div>
   ...
   </body>
   ```

   And I do...

   ```
   var el1 = document.getElementById('div-9999999'),
       el2 = document.getElementById('div-9999999-1-2'),
       el3 = document.getElementById('div-9999999-1-2-999999'),
       el4 = document.getElementById('div-9999999-1-2-999999-1-2-3-4-5');
   ```

   ... it could be much slower than

   ```
   var el1 = document.getElementById('div-9999999'),
       el2 = el1.getElementById('div-9999999-1-2'),
       el3 = el2.getElementById('div-9999999-1-2-999999'),
       el4 = el3.getElementById('div-9999999-1-2-999999-1-2-3-4-5');
   ```

   (Of course, this example is a simplification, and in this case using `.childNodes[]` or `.children[]` would be much better);

**Then, why doesn't `.getElementById` work on a node? I don't see any disadvantage, only advantages**

Comment: Well, ID's are unique on a page.

Comment: @elclanrs I know, but that doesn't mean that all nodes can't have `.getElementById()`

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting here, exactly?  It seems to me this is mostly opinion based.

Comment: @Daedalus I want, for example, a disadvantage of making `.getElementById` available on all nodes

Comment: let me introduce you to a friend of mine called [`element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

Comment: @Oriol Which falls to my second point.

Comment: *getElementById* might be available only on the document object, but *querySelector* is available for all nodes. *querySelector* on nodes works similarly to the way you described, and you could achieve the same functionality with it. **Edit:** hm... 2 minutes too late :P

Comment: `why` tag is very new to me.

Comment: If you want a real reason as to why it's not viable to implement `getElementById()` at the node level: efficiency. At the document level, a single ID reference table needs to be maintained, and any alterations to the document require an O(1) modification to this table. To implement it at the node level, an equivalent table would need to be maintained *for each node* and updates to any given element, regardless of whether it is attached to the document, would need to bubble through every one of its parent nodes. This very quickly eats a lot of memory and takes a long time to update the DOM.

Comment: @TheMask No longer; if the tag did exist, I would have sent a request to burninate it given the content.

Comment: @DaveRandom Ah, now I understand. If you write your comment in an answer (before my question gets closed), I will mark it as accepted answer

Comment: @Oriol I'm kind of torn over whether to answer this question or not, it definitely veers dangerous close to "primarily opinion based" - however, it's a question I can see others asking (and I can't find a surviving duplicate) so I have added my answer below for the benefit of future visitors. It's worth noting that you can achieve the functionality you want with *nearly* the same efficiency using `querySelector(All)?` because this uses the CSS selector engine cache for elements on the DOM, although for elements that only exist in JS and not attached to the DOM you risk `O(log n)`

Comment: I think with a slight rewording of the Title and Question, this will be perfectly legitimate and useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary reason is efficiency.

At the document level, a single ID reference table needs to be maintained, and any alterations to the document require an [`O(1)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) modification to this table. To implement it at the node level, an equivalent table would need to be maintained *for each node* and updates to any given element, regardless of whether it is attached to the document, would need to bubble through every one of its parent nodes. This very quickly eats a lot of memory and takes a long time to update the DOM.

Another important thing to note is that (from a Javascript point of view, at least) *every* element is owned by a document (or document fragment). Therefore the argument of "but I can have duplicated IDs as long as only one of them is attached to the document" doesn't really stack up - it's *only* possible to manage this based on the nodes on the DOM when you take this into account.

Comment: Very nice answer. My small addition is that essentially, what you're looking for is className's; those were never really specified to be *just* for CSS use.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the problems that you have described in your first example/requirement. As [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) only exists on the `document` node, because it make use of caches that are only provided by a node tree being part of `document`. You have three choices for searching a node tree that is not attached to the `document`. All suffer 0(log n) as they are not taking advantage of the `document` caches, there is little or no way around this (you tried with an `iFrame`).

**One: A recursive node walker.**

*Advantage is that this is cross-browser friendly*

*Disadvantage is that it will always be 0(log n) - if used on `document`*

Javascript

```
function getElementById(node, id) {
    if (node.id === id) {
        return node;
    }

    var target;

    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        target = getElementById(node, id);
        if (target) {
            return target;
        }

        node = node.nextSibling;
    }

    return undefined;
}

function foo(html) {
    var el = document.createElement("div");

    el.innerHTML = html;

    var target = getElementById(el, "target");

    /* Do something with `target` */
    if (target) {
        console.log(target);
    }
}

foo('<div id="nottarget1"><div id="nottarget2"><div id="nottarget3"><div id="nottarget4"><div id="target">Target</div></div></div></div></div>');
```

​
On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/YJHv7/)

**Two: using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector) which is available per element.**

*Advantage is that it requires less code*

*Disadvantage is that it requires IE8+ (and IE8 itself has limitations on the CSS query)*

Javascript

```
function getElementById(node, id) {    
    return node.querySelector("#" + id);
}

function foo(html) {
    var el = document.createElement("div");

    el.innerHTML = html;

    var target = getElementById(el, "target");

    /* Do something with `target` */
    if (target) {
        console.log(target);
    }
}

foo('<div id="nottarget1"><div id="nottarget2"><div id="nottarget3"><div id="nottarget4"><div id="target">Target</div></div></div></div></div>');
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/djNB9/)

**Three is to use [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/treeWalker)**

*Disadvantages are that it requires IE9+, is less understood (often forgotten) than the previous methods, and requires more code than `querySelector`*

Javascript

```
function getElementById(node, id) {
    return document.createTreeWalker(node, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, {
        acceptNode: function (n) {
            if (n.id === id) {
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
            }
        }
    }, false).nextNode();
}

function foo(html) {
    var el = document.createElement("div");

    el.innerHTML = html;

    var target = getElementById(el, "target");

    /* Do something with `target` */
    if (target) {
        console.log(target);
    }
}

foo('<div id="nottarget1"><div id="nottarget2"><div id="nottarget3"><div id="nottarget4"><div id="target">Target</div></div></div></div></div>');
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/s6WhU/)

Now, regarding performance of these methods, please see this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/three-getelementbyid)

**Note: The perfomance of the three methods will alter dramatically if the nodes are part of the `document`!**

Regarding your second desire, what you have described is a mute point due to the nature of `document` caches.

**Update:** If being asynchronous is not a problem for your requirement, then you can do it with an `iframe` like so.

*Advantage is that you can now use `getElementById`*

*Disadvantage is the huge overhead of creating and destroying the `iframe`*

Javascript

```
var getElementById = (function () {
    var parent = document.body || document.documentElement,
        javascript = "javascript";

    return function (node, id, func) {
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

        iframe.style.display = "none";
        iframe.src = javascript + ":";
        iframe.onload = function () {
            iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(node);
            func(iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById(id));
            parent.removeChild(iframe);
        };

        parent.appendChild(iframe);
    };
}());

function foo(html) {
    var el = document.createElement("div");

    el.innerHTML = html;
    getElementById(el, "target", function (target) {
        /* Do something with `target` */
        if (target) {
            console.log(target);
        }
    });
}

foo('<div id="nottarget1"><div id="nottarget2"><div id="nottarget3"><div id="nottarget4"><div id="target">Target</div></div></div></div></div>')
```

;

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/QStPr/)

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to avoid an expensive loop like that (another possible loop is iterate over `el.getElementsByTagName('*')`). I wanted a browser-native C/C++ compiled function to do that for me. And it seems that the solution is `querySelector()`, but it doesn't work on old browsers...

Comment: jsperf link is dead

Answer (score 0):

> "It could be possible to select nodes which don't belong to the
>   document."

Yes, but the method uses the fact that the id is unique in the document to optimise the performance. That's not possible if the element is not in a document.

> "It could increase the performance, if the document has lots of
>   elements and you know that the element you are searching is a
>   descendant of an element that you already have in a variable"

No, because it's already using a method that doesn't have to look through all the elements to find the id. Looping through elements would just make it slower.

Comment: Just adding on - I believe Webkit's implementation uses a [DocumentOrderedMap](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/core/dom/DocumentOrderedMap.h).  The actual method call is around Line 139 in [TreeScope](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/core/dom/TreeScope.cpp).